# To what degree of certainty is the Catholic Church condemnation of abortion infallible?

Tags: catholicism, abortion

It seems the Catholic condemnation of abortion has the same theological importance as the founding of the Catholic Church by Christ—i.e., that it's a dogma of faith (*de fide*) and morals (*moribus*).

John Paul II restates pronouncements of the "recent Papal Magisterium [that] has vigorously reaffirmed this common doctrine", the "the moral condemnation of abortion", in the encyclical [*Evangelium Vitæ*](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_25031995_evangelium-vitae.html) §62.

Comment: As far as the Catholic Church is considered, it is absolutely certain: abortion is a serious and immoral act. From the Early Church until the present moment the Church has not altered Her position on the matter (historically, morally or doctrinally). If your question states it is common doctrine why are you posing the question? Is there a doubt about the Church’s position on this matter?

Comment: @KenGraham  It looks like he asked it just to answer it himself so that he could complain about his perception that bishops and priests don't talk about it enough.

Comment: Why did my OP get two down votes? It seems totally unjustified. I presented the Catholic truth about abortion whereas two people doubt my intensions or inaccurately claim the church has not altered her position which she certainly has,, she upgraded it. Neither of them knew that the condemnation of abortion is equal importance to the founding of the church by Christ. Why the personal pushback?

Answer (score 0):

The Catholic Church's condemnation of abortion falls under [dogmas of faith and morals (*de fide et moribus*)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66381/1787).

Pope Pius XI's condemnation of contraception in the encyclical on Christian marriage, [*Casti Connubii*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_19301231_casti-connubii.html), [has been considered an *ex cathedra* (infallible) statement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66381/1787). What [Cartechini](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66381/1787) says regarding contraception can be applied [*mutatis mutandis*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutatis%20mutandis) to abortion:

> even if it is not a dogma of the faith, the doctrine he promulgated certainly is infallibly true because the Pope authoritatively and with solemn words expresses **a moral doctrine that from ancient times the [ordinary and universal magisterium](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34700) has constantly proposed must be be held and observed**.

As [*Evangelium Vitæ*](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_25031995_evangelium-vitae.html) §62 says, "**the moral condemnation of abortion**" "**is** based upon the natural law and upon the written Word of God, is transmitted by the Church's Tradition, and **taught by the ordinary and universal Magisterium**."

Comment: Does contraception include prophylactic practices such as engaging coitus only when the woman is most infertile, in order to prevent pregnancy?

Comment: @MikeBorden Let's keep to the subject matter. You can freely expand on this, simply ask another question if you desire.

Comment: @KenGraham The subject matter in OP is abortion and it is this answer which brings up contraception without demonstrating how contraception (especially preventative) and abortion are related.

Comment: @MikeBorden Condemnations of abortion and contraception are both doctrines taught by the ordinary and universal Magisterium.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and reviewed my previous posts and realized that critical parts were edited out or I missed them in my original post. Here are the two critical points that were missing in my original post:

1. Extract from EV #62:
   “Given such unanimity in the doctrinal and disciplinary tradition of the Church, Paul VI was able to declare that this tradition is unchanged and unchangeable. 72 Therefore, **by the authority which Christ conferred upon Peter** and his Successors, in communion with the Bishops-who on various occasions have condemned abortion and who in the aforementioned consultation, albeit dispersed throughout the world, have shown unanimous agreement concerning this doctrine-**I declare** that direct abortion, that is, abortion willed as an end or as a means, always constitutes a grave moral disorder, **since it is the deliberate killing of an innocent human being**. This doctrine is based upon the natural law and upon the written Word of God, is transmitted by the Church's Tradition and taught by the ordinary and universal Magisterium.”

The importance here is that in the prior paragraph the Pope reference 3 prior Popes and Vatican II. In this paragraph the Pope speaks with the authority of St. Peter and the world-wide bishops, Church tradition, natural law, the written word of God and taught by the ordinary and universal magisterium and DECLARES his condemnation of abortion with the authority of St. Peter. I wanted to clear this up so there would be no confusion that EV is not just a teaching, it is an infallible doctrine.

2. Doctrinal Commentary on the Concluding Formula of the Professio fidei:

paragraph 11. To the truths of the first paragraph belong the articles of faith of the Creed, the various christological dogmas21 and marian dogmas;22the doctrine of the institution of the sacraments by Christ and their efficacy with regard to grace;23the doctrine of the real and substantial presence of Christ in the Eucharist24and the sacrificial nature of the eucharistic celebration;25the foundation of the Church by the will of Christ;26the doctrine on the primacy and infallibility of the Roman Pontiff;27 the doctrine on the existence of original sin;28the doctrine on the immortality of the spiritual soul and on the immediate recompense after death;29the absence of error in the inspired sacred texts;30 **the doctrine on the grave immorality of direct and voluntary killing of an innocent human being.**31

This is the CONGREGATION FOR THE DOCTRINE OF THE FAITH expounding on the truths that are of Divine and Catholic Faith signed by Joseph Card. Ratzinger Prefect.

The last entry in #11 clearly puts the condemnation of abortion in the same Divine and Catholic Faith category as the founding of the Catholic Church by Christ, all the Marian doctrine and the Real Presence of Christ in the Eucharist.

This is really an astounding, staggering Catholic dogmatic statement on abortion that almost no Catholics, hierarchy, Bishops, theologians, apologists and laity are aware of. I am trying to change that, ergo the purpose of the topic- to save the unborn by telling the true seriousness of the condemnation of abortion.

Comment: If you want to add additional information to your original post, please do so. The OP cannot select more than one "Answer".

Answer (score -2):

Yes, informed Catholics know that the abortion is condemned by the Catholic Church. What is not known by most Catholics is two enhancements to the condemnation.

1. EV made the condemnation of abortion an infallible dogma where as previously it was a definitive teaching.
2. EV elevated the condemnation of abortion to the same category as the founding of the Catholic Church by Christ, The Real Presence in the Eucharist and all the Marion dogmas and more. It is a dogma of Divine and Catholic Faith and doubters and deniers are considered heretics from the Catholic Faith.

This happened 23 years ago but I have never heard a Cardinal, Bishop, apologist or theologian mention its grave seriousness equal to the highest dogmas. Never. I had never known this until this week and I would imagine very few Catholics have ever heard this. I have talked to many Catholics who did not know it was an infallible dogma much less a dogma equal to the founding of the Church by Christ. This is actually a staggering denunciation of abortion and all Catholics should be aware it instead of complete silence about its exalted category.

Why would the current Pope and Bishops not tell all Catholics how important this dogma is?

Comment: Our Bishop Council in America has been saying for years that abortion is *the* pre-eminent issue for American Catholics. I don't know where you are getting this idea that its importance is not stressed. We have bishops, priests, and apologists praying memorares hourly on our national radio station for an end to abortion. What else could pre-eminent mean?

Comment: The Church has condemned abortion as a grave sin, centuries before ***Evangelium Vita***. There is nothing new about this topic. Pope St. Paul VI speaks of it in ***Humanae Vitae***. Should I go on... Political leaders are often in the news when it comes to supporting abortion and going to communion. I do agree with one thing here, the Bishops have to step up to the in the political arena and clearly make the call that such support and receiving communion are not to be tolerated. If in the Middle Ages, such politicians would be placed under interdict!

Comment: jaredad7 – My point is that NO current Catholic Pope or Bishop is proclaiming that the condemnation is equal in importance to the founding of the Catholic Church by Christ which they are ignorant of or dismiss it as unimportance which is a tragedy. Witness the recent Bishops conference where it was never said or discussed. Ken Graham – it was NEW in 1998 that the condemnation of abortion is equal in kind to the founding of the Church by Christ. I think there is not 1 Catholic in a thousand who know this. It seems that you did not know it. Please help me spread the word to Catholics about this.

Comment: @chrisgriffin Have you asked the bishops? Priests and bishops in my diocese constantly speak about it. Pope Francis has equally done so. Where are you getting your information from?

Comment: @Ken Graham, I am an active pro-lifer and keep up with all aspects of abortion. I have never heard any Catholic say that the condemnation of abortion is equal in Divine and Catholic Faith to the founding of the Catholic Church by Christ. Not the Pope nor Bishop nor priest nor apologist nor Catholic website. In my opinion this is tremendous failure to deny the laity the staggering truth of Catholic dogma about abortion. The Pope rarely speaks about abortion. He was publicly silent when abortion was legalized in Ireland and Argentina. I hope popularizing this dogma will save the unborn.